# How do I escape from a full-screen apllication?

Tags: gui, fullscreen

I have a really old laptop, but since its Ubuntu, it's basically brand new.

One problem I do have with it, though, is the fact that whenever I use Skype or YouTube (or Half-Life) it breaks, and I can't escape. The only way to get out of it is to hold down the power button, which makes me feel like I'm damaging it.

A friend told me it was something to do with drivers. If I press <kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd>, I can't remember) it goes to the terminal, but this is also full screened and can't exit. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Is unfullscreen a word? (Autocheck comes up with "sunscreen")

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to AskUbuntu and I'm glad that Ubuntu is *mostly* working well on your old laptop. Could you please edit your question to describe what exactly you mean when you say "it breaks"? What do you see on the screen?

Comment: I believe what you are doing is Alt+F1 or Alt+F2, and if that is the case, press Alt+F7 to get back to your GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If by "breaks", you mean that it freezes up, there are a few methods to try to fix things.

### Wait a few minutes

Wait a few minutes and the problem might clear itself up. This is particularly apt for older machines.

### Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Like Windows, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will try to nicely close the focused application. Try that and give it a minute or so to work through closing itself.

### Use `xkill`

`xkill` can be useful in not-so-nicely (i.e., it doesn't give the application time to save things to disk, so things may be broken or not saved) terminating full-screen applications that have completely frozen:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal within the GUI
2. Run `xkill & exit` to turn the mouse cursor into an `×` and to close the terminal
3. Left click on the stalled application to attempt to terminate it